# Sorting email in dataframe columns with domain name

Tags: python, pandas

```
for i in emails:
    if emails.str.contains(pat='@gent.edu')=="True":
        needac.append(i)
```

Am trying to sort out a column containing email address in my one column dataframe (emails) using the email domain "@gent.edu", but I keep getting this error "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: There's not enough information to understand your question. Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with sample input and expected output.

Comment: If you are using the `series.str.contains()` method of a pandas series, it already returns an array of booleans, so looping through it and comparing it to string "True" are both unnecessary. For example, needac=emails[emails.str.contains(pat)].tolist()` could be a solution but it's hard to know without more detail

Comment: do you want to **sort** or to **filter**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this by using the piece of code

```
f.dropna()

mail_list = []
pattern = r'.(@gent\.edu)'
for i in list(f):
    matched = re.search(pattern, i)
    if matched:
        mail_list.append(i)
```

Running this code without the dropna method will give the error:
"TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

The pattern has to include a backslash before the dot symbol because the dot symbol has a meaning in python re library.

Answer (score 0):

#### to filter

```
df[df['email'].str.match('.*@gent.edu$')]
```

#### to sort

You can use `sort_values` with the `key` parameter:

```
df.sort_values(by='email', key=lambda s: s.str.split('@').str[::-1])
```

*NB. this works only with "simple" emails in the form "prefix@domain" where there is only a single "@" symbol.*

example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'email': ['nameC@def.org',
                             'nameB@abc.org',
                             'nameA@abc.org',
                             'nameD@def.org',
                            ]})
```

output:

```
           email
2  nameA@abc.org
1  nameB@abc.org
0  nameC@def.org
3  nameD@def.org
```